# Using Sequences with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a sequence with a table `MiCliente` the sequence must be eliminate if this exist, must be one by one and with a cycle and it needs to start with 1000. I need to associate the sequence with a column `MiCliente.idCliente`.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MiCliente
(
    idCliente          int             NOT NULL,
    idMunicipio        int             NOT NULL,
    cedula             varchar(20)     NOT NULL,
    nombres            varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
    apellidos          varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
    idSexo             char(1)         NULL,
    idEstadoCivil      tinyint         NULL,
    fechaNacimiento    date            NULL,
    telefono           varchar(20)     NULL,
    celular            varchar(20)     NULL,
    direccion          varchar(100)    NULL,
    email              varchar(100)    NULL     
);
GO

Create Sequence Conteo  
AS tinyint   
START WITH 1000   
INCREMENT BY 1   
GO
```

When I execute the query I receive

> error 343

Comment: FYI, `TINYINT` is for values 0 to 255.

Comment: Sequences are a SQL sever 2012 and onward feature. Please add appropriate tag in the question so that it is clear to the readers.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe an identity field would solve your problem best.  You can't really associate a sequence with a table field; at least not by definition.  A sequence can be used as a type of "counter" object and can be invoked for a table to generate a value that gets inserted into a table.

(here is a good discussion on using sequences: 
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-sequence-basics/)

For example, using the sequence you created in your example (keep in mind, as ZLK comments, tinyint is for values from 0 to 255; you should use int) one could say:

```
select (next value for Conteo) idCliente, cedula, email from dbo.MiCliente;
```

or something like

```
INSERT INTO MiCliente
(idCliente, idMunicipio, cedula, nombres, apellidos)
VALUES
(NEXT VALUE FOR Conteo, 1,'test','Smith','test2');
```

So this works, but one could reference the same sequence for another table as well.  So it isn't specifically "tied" to your table.  It may not matter though.

On the other hand, you could set idCliente as an identity field such that it also begins with 1000.  This is "tied" to the table and, in my opinion, is easier to use.  The number just get generated automatically.

So you might do something like:

```
Alter table dbo.MiCliente add idCliente INT IDENTITY(1000,1)
```

And then you can make it your primary key as well:

```
alter table dbo.MiCliente add constraint PK_MiCliente PRIMARY KEY(idCliente)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I executed your query it simply gives following error:

> Msg 11708, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   An invalid value was specified for argument 'START WITH' for the given data type.

It is clearly evident of the fact that you are using wrong data type `tinyint` while creating the sequence. Changing it to `int` should solve your problem. Here is the modified query. Hope this helps!

```
Create Sequence Conteo  
AS int   
START WITH 1000   
INCREMENT BY 1   
GO
```

I was able to create the sequence successfully after making this change. I'm on SQL Server 2012.